# ambari metrics diskspacecheck issue

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am installing a new hadoop cluster(total 5 nodes) using the Ambari dashboard. While deploying the cluster it fails but with warnings of disk space issues and error messages like '/' needs atleast 2GB of diskspace for mount. But I have allocated total 50GB of disk to each node. Upon googling for the solution I found that I need to make diskspacecheck=0 in the etc/yum.conf file as suggested in the below link(point 3.6):
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_ambari_troubleshooting/content/_resolving_ambari_installer_problems.html

But I am using ubuntu image in the nodes and there is no yum file. And I didn't get any file with "diskspacecheck" parameter. Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue and successfully deploy my cluster?

Comment: Can you provide the error stack trace that you are seeing when trying to deploy the cluster?

Comment: I have finally resolved the problem. It was not because of the Hadoop distribution but due to the compute instance not having enough storage mounted with root directory ("/"). Generally, in OpenStack kind of cloud environment very small root space is provisioned even if you had asked for the larger storage up front while creating an instance.
To verify root space we need to run "df -h" command on all the nodes (especially the NameNode) and check how much space is available for "/".

Comment: And then we can increase the root partition volume group by using the commands in the following url:
http://www.joomlaworks.net/blog/item/168-resizing-the-disk-space-on-ubuntu-server-vms-running-on-vmware-esxi-5